# How to get an element's index by using xPath and text value

Tags: dom, text, xpath, indexing, element

I have following structure

```
<div class='list'>
  <div class='column'>aaa</div>
  <div class='column'>bbb</div>
   ...
  <div class='column'>jjj</div>
</div>
```

I'm new to xpath, so it'll be very helpful to get an assistance.
I would like to get the index of the element with text value "aaa" for examp, so I would expect to get an int = 1 / 0...

Thanks

Comment: `count(//div[.='aaa']/preceding-sibling::div)`?

Comment: @Wrikken add it as an answer so lgal can set the question as solved.